# Xilinx error: Port connections cannot be mixed ordered and named

Tags: xilinx

```
FA FA9(.in0(CSA10[0]), .in1(CSA11[0]), .carry_in(CSA12[0]), .sum(CSA20[0]), carry_out(CSA20[1]));
```

For the above line of code, I got error "Port connections cannot be mixed ordered and named". All the CSAs are declared as wire [1:0] CSA11, CSA12, etc. The tool I am using is Xilinx 14.7.

I think the port connection I am using in the above statement is only named connection.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you missed the "." before "carry_out".  Try this:

```
FA FA9(.in0(CSA10[0]), .in1(CSA11[0]), .carry_in(CSA12[0]), .sum(CSA20[0]), .carry_out(CSA20[1]));
```